# Set a threshold for each point

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3.js

[image: A mockup of the 10-3-2-1]

I have used C3.js to create a bar chart very similar to this, but the problem am facing is setting a threshold for every point on the bar as regards to the value on the x-axis. For instance when the GOAL is `< 10%` on the x-axis there should be a dotted line exactly on the `10%` mark on the y-axis and the same thing should happen for the subsequent value i.e `<3%, <2% and <1%`.

My question is, please how do I create the threshold or set a mark on the chart like it is on the mockup? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same functions that c3 uses to draw the bars to figure out where to draw your target lines, like so

```
...

// where to draw the target lines for each data point
var scalingFactors = [0.1, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01]

// svg layer for each bar series
var barsLayers = chart.internal.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.bars)[0]
var bars = chart.internal.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.bar)[0];
// use the same function c3 uses to get each bars corners
var getPoints = chart.internal.generateGetBarPoints(chart.internal.getShapeIndices(chart.internal.isBarType));
// just in case there are multiple series
chart.internal.data.targets.forEach(function (series, i) {
    // for each point in the series
    series.values.forEach(function (d, j) {
        // highlight if over threshold
        if (d.value > scalingFactors[j])
            d3.select(bars[j]).classed('crossed', true);

        // get the position for our target lines
        var value = d.value;
        d.value = scalingFactors[j];
        var pos = getPoints(d, j);
        d.value = value;

        var posTopLeft = pos[1]
        var posTopRight = pos[2]

        // draw target lines
        d3.select(barsLayers[i]).append("line")
            .attr("x1", posTopLeft[0] - 10)
            .attr("y1", posTopLeft[1])
            .attr("x2", posTopRight[0] + 10)
            .attr("y2", posTopRight[1])
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .style("stroke-dasharray", ("6, 4"));
    })
})
```

**CSS**

```
.crossed {
   fill: orange !important;
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/puvhLb6x/

---

[image]

Comment: This is so helpful...I really really appreciate this, but I want the second bars to change to color whenever it passes its own threshold

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle

Comment: @potatopeelings Hi! This is just the answer I am looking for but it is kind of old so I was getting ` ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CLASS')`
I found out that they changed it a little bit and I became with
`chart.internal.api.load({type: "bar"})` but I still couldn't draw the lines I started getting an error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') for the line starts with `d3.select` .  Can you post a more up to date code?